# Keep getting a first chance exception error

Tags: vb.net, exception

When i run my program the code catches the timeout exception correctly but then i get a popup message saying:

> A first chance exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll

Also says this:

> Object variable or With block variable not set.

Here is my code:

```
Dim rt As String = ""
Dim out As String
Dim wRequest As WebRequest
Dim wResponse As WebResponse
Dim SR As StreamReader
Dim time As Date

time = Now()

Try
    wRequest = WebRequest.Create(Address)
    wRequest.Timeout = 10000
    wResponse = wRequest.GetResponse
    SR = New StreamReader(wResponse.GetResponseStream)
    rt = SR.ReadToEnd
    SR.Close()
Catch wex As System.Net.WebException
    If wex.Status = WebExceptionStatus.Timeout Then
        MessageBox.Show("Could not establish a connection to the selected exchange server.", "Connection Timed Out", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning)
    End If
End Try
```

Comment: Do you have a line number where the exception was raised?

Comment: It says line 107 which is If wex.Status = WebExceptionStatus.Timeout Then

Comment: Set a breakpoint there and inspect the stacktrace of `wex`.

Comment: Revised my first post.

Comment: Maybe use `System.TimeoutException`, thus avoiding the if statement altogether.

Comment: Maybe "double catch" will help .. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/es54hw8e.aspx

Comment: @HanletEscaño But i need the if statement to show the messagebox to the user to tell them the connection failed.

Comment: If you are just interested in catching the TimeOut (which apparently you are) just get the messagebox inside, otherwise do as matzone says and either catch everything, or double catch.